# menu as data source for android listview?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-listview

I am confused about how common listview pattern works.

In all guides that I found I see something like:

1. Write your menu items in a string array(in XML or in code).
2. Set that array as data source for list view.
3. If user click(select) any item, get index of that item and than somehow figure out what you should do(check it with case construction or whatever)

And even that is not all.

Appearance. What if I want to set a different icon for each list item? Looping through that list again and setting corresponding icons just looks stupid.

But. Maybe I am missing something?

Is it possible to use something like that:

(pseudocode)

```
<menu id="list">
    <item name="first" icon="icon1.png">First</item>
    <item name="second" icon="icon2.png">Second</item>
    <item name="third" icon="icon3.png">Third</item>
</menu>
...
<listview  entries="@list"></listview>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much totally confused.

A ListView has nothing to do with menus.  A ListView is a widget that allows an infinite number of rows, displays a subset of those rows on the screen, and provides efficient scrolling.  That's all.

ListViews have adapters.  Adapters allow you to take a data structure and map them to row positions in a list view.  The also define how a row looks on screen, by providing a getView function that the ListVIew uses as the view for the row.  There's built in adapters to do very simple stuff, and if you want to do something more complicated its trivial to write your own.

And that's the basic of listviews.

Comment: I am confused because I looked at menu structure, and menu item does have pretty rich markup, but listview items does not, but in general that should(at least i think so). Can you please explain how to make listview look like in native android settings app(with icons and division headings)? or maybe it is possible to make menu to look like listview?

Comment: You keep thinking these two things are related.  They aren't.  THere is no connection between menus and listviews.  A listview is just a generic view that has an infinite number of rows.  A menu is something else.  And the native android settings app is a completely different thing altogehter-  it's a PreferenceActivity, with a series of Preferences inside of it.

Comment: Just about Settings app, I wanted to point how it looks, just to let you know what I mean, anyway, thanks!